# ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms causes nullreferenceexception in Android app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I added the ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms to generate QR codes in my app. As the documentation said, I added `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();` to my MainActivity.cs file. I also gave my app the permissions to use Camera and Flashlight. However when I run it I get this error on LoadApplication(new App());

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.InternalSetPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x0005e] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:315 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.SetMainPage () [0x00000] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:343 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.LoadApplication (Xamarin.Forms.Application application) [0x0025c] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:139 
  at Silenda.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0002e] in C:\Users\arnva\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Silenda\Silenda\Silenda.Android\MainActivity.cs:24 }
```

Comment: why should be a ZXing problem?

Comment: If I remove the ZXing library I no longer have this problem

Comment: try using an earlier version and clean solution + restart VS

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/657

Comment: Cleaning solution and downgrading did indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

Update the xamarin.forms version to latest